# Why is this particular keystroke (shown inline) highlighted in VIM version 8.0 under Cygwin, and how to remove it?

Tags: cygwin

Whenever I write `];`, in VIM-80 under Cygwin, these symbols get highlighted in yellow. This is a bit annoying and I want it removed.

Following the on-line help I found the file "usr_44.txt", regarding syntax highlighting. I tried the command `:syntax clear`, but no luck.

It may well be the case that this stems from me learning VIM, pressing keys frustrated while stuck in the editor. Anyway, how can I remove it ?

Comment: “Whenever”—all types of files, only c code, etc? The question is pretty unclear and could use more detail

Comment: Whenever - e.g. no filetype specified, so yes: all types of files. Sorry bout question being unclear. If I write "];", which I often do, particularly for c-files, then these keys gets highlighted in yellow

Comment: Can you find out what syntax group they apply to or what highlight is “yellowing” them? Have you tried “nohlsearch” to turn off highlighting from the last search?

Comment: Could this be the [`matchparen`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_paren.txt.html#matchparen) that you're seeing?

Comment: Are you able to identify which highlight groups are being used following this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor Also, have you tried starting vim without a vimrc, or enabling/disabling plugins to narrow down a cause?

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble - The "nohlsearch" did the trick. Thanks and happy new year. Cheers and greetings from the north

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As determined in the comments, `];` formed the last search pattern (as set by `:global`, `:substitute`, `/`, or `?`—cf. `:help quote_/`), and `'hlsearch'` was `set`.

Therefore, the characters were highlighted (usually a distinct yellow).

The solution to (temporarily) stop the highlight is `:nohlsearch`.